# InputStream wrapper that closes the stream once reading is done

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, blob, inputstream

I faced some issues in a project with spring and hibernate where the stream given to Blob is not closed.

```
Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(currentSession).createBlob(inputStream, size);
```

I can't use things like `try with resources` since the stream is only read after the transaction commits. I've tried closing the stream using hibernate's `@PostPersist` as well. It works in persist situations but causes problems of Blob already being freed with `CascadeType.MERGE` scenarios.

One of my friends suggested a hacky way to handle this. Basically, his idea was to write a wrapper which closes the stream once the reading is complete.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class SelfClosingInputStream extends InputStream {

    private InputStream inputStream;

    public SelfClosingInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        try {
            int val = this.inputStream.read();
            if (val != -1) {
                return val;
            } else {
                this.inputStream.close();
                return -1;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.inputStream.close();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

I've done a simple test and it works. I understand that there can be a performance issue with the if check. However, I think there are other caveats in this as well. Can someone shed some light on those?

```
Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(currentSession).createBlob(new SelfClosingInputStream(inputStream), size);
```

P.S: I've already posted it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196274/inputstream-wrapper-that-closes-the-stream-once-reading-is-done) at code review but only got a very few responses. Hence reposting here with some updates.

UPDATE:

Received a good amount of feedback from code review. This [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/196314/88998) seems to give the most correct way of doing it.

Further https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/AutoCloseInputStream.html gives a similar implementation.

Comment: Code Review is the right place for this question.  It is too open-ended for SO.

Comment: Just found that https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/AutoCloseInputStream.html does the same thing as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int read()  throws IOException {
    try {
        this.inputStream.read();
        if (val != -1) {
            return val;
        } else {
            this.inputStream.close();
            return -1;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Something is wrong!");
    } finally {
    try {
            if (this.inputStream != null) {
            this.inputStreamObj.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

you must force the `close()` with finally block if `this.inputStream` is not null.

Comment: This is wrong - because it would close the stream as soon as the first byte is read!

Comment: The finally for closure is not what you are commenting. You are commenting regarding the `if` after the first read (and indeed, it should be a `while` loop).

That said, for his question, you must consider `this.inputStream.read()` at a given point an exception happens reading the resource, the inputStream will remain open because the if condition to go to the `.close()` will never happen. If happens, you have to close the inputStream to prevent resource leak.

Comment: Agreed regarding the concern that `close()` would not be called on the wrapped stream in case of an intermediary failure; I believe you intended to add the nested `try`-`catch` inside the top-level `catch` so that the closure happens only during an exception. (Not sure what you meant by "(the first `read()`) should be (inside?) a `while` loop", though, since the intention of `read()` is to just read and return a single byte; and I _was_ indeed referring to the  closure inside `finally`.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure stream is not freed? Because looking at [`BlobProxy`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/BlobProxy.java) code when you (or Hibernate) release the blob calling `Blob#free()` via BlobProxy implementation an `InputStream#close()` is performed and your stream should be correctly close.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, Blob.free() is not called automatically. I have posted this as a separate question here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848513/how-to-release-blobs-with-hibernate-and-spring-transactional